# Infinite scroll with vue and mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, vue.js, infinite-scroll

I want to implement infinite-scrolling in my vueApp.

I'm using mongo, node, vue, mongoose and having problems to understand the logic on the server-side.

my issue is this:
let's say I have a collection with 3 million documents,
when the user is scrolling down he will get 5 documents every time.
how I'm implementing this into a mongo query that will send 5 documents each time and will know to proceed from the last record it sent once its called again?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: In short to say, "we'd love to answer". However you would more likely get a better overall answer by asking each of the questions separately. There are many moving parts in what you ask. Ask a question about how to do "each step" instead, and then you will most likely get the "total answer".

Comment: thanks for the info
i will edit my question

Answer (score 2):

You can try applying the logic applied to pagination, that is when the user reaches the down, increment the page number and pass it to the query to fetch new records!